# Drupal doesn't generate thumbnails

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I don't know why Drupal stopped generating thumbnails. So, I get error on files like this:

/sites/default/files/styles/choices/public/a1531172504.jpg?itok=Wn-VWDKd

Although the full image is found in:

/sites/default/files/a1531172504.jpg

I'm working on Nginx, Drupal 7

Comment: could be a file permissions issue.  Check your file system especially for /sites/default/files/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last time I've answers question related to image derivatives I've got minuses so let be thorough here.

1.Drupal core will NOT create image derivative upon image upload - fact.

2.Thumbnail image (derivative from original image) is physically created upon HTTP request eg. if you visit the listing where image is used (when you visit the listing with thumbnail image the derivative is created on the fly via HTTP request)

3.To alter this behavior and to get a derivative image instantly upon image upload via CCK field you must use module **Imageinfo Cache** https://www.drupal.org/project/imageinfo_cache

With this info form above please recheck your site (go to listing where the thumbnail should appear and than check your thumbnail folder) If the image is still missing please provide more details like: Are you using CCK field or is it a custom field, are you creating derivative programmatically? Some code snippets are required here to solve you problem.

Also please check your .htaccess located in sites/default/files/.htaccess (not the general .htaccess)
and while you there check the permissions on files folder.

Comment: I've installed imageinfo_cache module, and it solved the problem. The problem was because (as you said) Drupal generate the thumbnail on request only. So, when the image requested, if it gives 404 error, Drupal will generate it. At this satge, Nginx should pass the 404 error to Drupal, but it doesn't do. I tried many methods to do that, but I failed. So, the easiest solution as you said is to add this module.
Thank you

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to add this lines to the `nginx.conf` files:

```
location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    # not working with Drupal rewrite module: rewrite ^/?(.*?)/?$  /index.php?q=$1&$args;
    rewrite ^/?(.*?)/?$  /index.php/$1&$args;
}
```

My environment is:

```
 - docker-compose with nginx (nginx:1.17.4-alpine), drupal   
   (drupal:9.0.6-fpm-alpine) and mysql (mysql:8.0)
 - drupal (9.0.6),    nginx/1.17.4, PHP 7.4.10, MySql 8.0.21
```

The server responded with a `404 error` because:

- The image styles are generated when drupal receives a request.
- Nginx receives a request for an image that is not in the filesystem; then returns a 404 instead redirect the request to drupal.

The rule I propose for the `nginx.conf` redirect the image request to `drupal` and solve the problem after restart the web server:

```
docker-compose restart webserver
```

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to disable and re-enable the clean-url. `.../admin/config/search/clean-urls"`.